# How to receive multiple Data in controller side using FormData(Ajax)?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, form-data

My ajax has used FormData and append multiple Field value (like Text-box,label,File) in single(FormData) object. and i have posted that data at server side but

How to receive same data object in controller?

FormData variable :

```
var uploadFile = new FormData();
        var files = $("#UploadFile").get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            uploadFile.append("Doc", files[0]);
        }
  FileUpload(uploadFile);
```

Javasacript method Ajax Call :

```
 function FileUpload(uploadFile)
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("UploadCsvFile")';

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data:uploadFile,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function () {
            alert("Successfully Added & processed");

        }
    });
```

My Question is....if in case,My ajax has more Data, How to receive the same data in controller side and what, if i want to use specific Data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can receive customized forms that are quite complex***

It will work in two parts:

**Part 1 - Extending the html FormData:**

```
uploadFile.append("TextData", "This is my text data");
```

**Part 2 - Extending your controller:**

I assume your model would look something like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
     public HttpPostedFileBase Doc{ get; set;}
}
```

Now just add your custom data to it:

```
public string TextData {get;set;}
```

And in your controller method:

```
public JsonResult MyUploadMethod(MyModel model)
{
    /*From here you will have access to the file and the text data*/
}
```

Hope it helps. Ask me any questions if you need help.

Comment: This is really very helpful answer, i will defiantly implement this

Comment: Please feel free to edit your question with more details, or mark this as the answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: There is one thing i dont get about this answer. In the Controller method, shouldn't the variable "model" be called "Doc"? I'm having this question and cant get the file in FormData to be recognized by any name. I cant just receive it has Request.Files["name"], but I do a ModelState.IsValid before, and cant make it because cant receive the file in MyModel var...

Comment: To answer your question, no. The model you send should be called model and then the two properties on the model will be called Doc and TextData respectively: var model = ```{"Doc" : document, "TextData" : "My Text data"}```